# Flat UI not compatible with Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, flat

Flat ui by Designmodo does not work in Chrome at all, is it a certain javascript that causes this mess?

Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m
OS: Win XP
Flat UI: http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by web kit 3d transform, see https://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using Flat-UI, and in Chrome everything is showing up Fine. Look up your Chrome extensions !